# Prove that $C_H(K)=N_H(K)$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ & $K$ be groups. Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from K into $Aut(H)$. Identify $H$ & $K$ as subgroups of $G=H\rtimes_{\phi}K$.

Prove that $C_H(K)=N_H(K)$.

Comment: Which step is giving you a headache? Can you show inclusion one way or the other?

Comment: This seems to be a task. What is your question?

Comment: Yeah $C_H(K) \subseteq N_K(K)$ is ok. For other part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case, it is always true that $\;C_H(K)\subset N_H(K)\;$, and in fact $\;C_H(K)\lhd N_H(K)\;$

Take now $\;h\in N_H(K)\;$ , then using the semidirect product usual notation, we get that for any $\;k\in K\;$ there exists $\;k'\in K\;$ s.t.

$$(1,k')=(h,1)(1,k)(h^{-1},1)=(h,k)(h^{-1},1)=(hh^{-k},k)$$

and thus we must have

$$hh^{-k}=1\iff h=h^k=k^{-1}hk\iff kh=hk\implies h\in C_H(K)$$